# C++ pointer to a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

In my code I  would like to call different functions by the same name. So I used pointers, and I did work with static functions, now I would like to do the same with non-static functions and it doesn't work at all.

```
class Amrorder
:   {
public:
   ....
    void (*fkt)(real&, const real);
    void fktAcPulse(real &rhoRef, const real y);
    void fktAcPulseSol(real &rhoRef, const real y);
...
}

void Amrorder::initData(a)
{
...
 switch(method){
    case 2://
      Amrorder::fkt=&Amrorder::fktAcPulse;
      break;
    case 222://
      Amrorder::fkt=&Amrorder::fktAcPulse1d;
      break;
    }
...
  for(int i=0; i<ng; ++i){ 
    Amrorder::fkt(rhoRef, yRef);
    ...
  }
...
}
```

The code is quiet big so I hope the part above is enough to understand what I want to do.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Learn [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and learn about [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)  and [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) i.e. [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). See also [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: A pointer to a non-member function is not the same as a pointer to a non-static member function. Your variable `fkt` is a pointer to a non-member function.

Comment: Look up syntax for "pointer-to-member function".

Comment: Required reading: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html (It might be a bit old-fashioned with C++11 around, but is still required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **type** of `fkt` declares a function pointer to a free-standing function or a static member function. But you want to assign a non-static member function pointer to it. So `fkt` needs to be of the type of a non-static member function pointer of class `Amrorder`. That type is spelled

```
void (Amrorder::*fkt)(real&, const real);
//    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

When **invoking** a function pointer to a non-static member function, you need to specify *on which object* you want the member to be called (which normally defaults to `this` when calling a member function directly with its name).

The syntax for this is quite strange. It requires another pair of parentheses and depends on wether you call it on a pointer or an object itself:

```
(object.*functionPointer)(arguments);
(pointer->*functionPointer)(arguments);
```

So if you just want to call the function **on the `this` pointer**, you need to write

```
(this->*fkt)(rhoRef, yRef);
```

(Note that you don't need to specify the class in your code everywhere. `Amrorder::` can be removed in front of every function name inside the definition of a member function of the same class.)

Comment: Even so this looks quiet  strange to me, it dose exactly what I want. 
So thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because your `fkt` has type:

```
void (*)(real&, const real);
```

and you're trying to assign it to, e.g., `&Amrorder::fktAcPulse`, which has type:

```
void (Amrorder::*)(real&, const real);
```

Notice the difference. The latter is a *pointer-to-member* function, not just a pointer to function. These have different semantics. A pointer to function can just be called (e.g. `fkt(a, b)`), but a pointer to member function needs to be called on an object (e.g. `(obj.*pm)(a, b)`).

For simplicity, since you probably just want "something that I can call with a `real&` and a `const real`", you may want to consider the type-erased function object: [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
std::function<void(real&, const real)> fkt;
```

This can be initialized with any callable that matches the arguments, so you can assign it to a free function:

```
void foo(real&, const real) { ... }
fkt = foo;
```

A static member function:

```
struct S { static void bar(real&, const real) { ... } };
fkt = &S::bar;
```

Or a member function, as long as its [*bound*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
fkt = std::bind(&Amrorder::fktAcPulse, this);
fkt = [this](real& a, const real b){ return this->fktAcPulse(a, b); };
```

The key is that you need an instance of `Amrorder` to call `fktAcPulse`, and using `std::function` lets you use either `std::bind` or a lambda to store that instance in with the functor itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a non-static method of a class, the compiler needs to know which instance of the class you want to execute against.  So there is a hidden parameter in the call, which is a pointer to the instance.

So you need to write something like this:

```
Amrorder::fkt=bind( &Amrorder::fktAcPulse, this );
```